# Webpack assets build is not working on webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, plugins, webpack

How assets section is working ? 
During build it gives expected result - languages extended.
But once running `webpack-dev-server` it gives assets from file (not extended) - assets is built.
As i know `webpack` should load all assets into memory, why it gives assets from file and not built assets ?

Thanks

```
compiler.plugin('emit', function (compilation, callback) {
    console.log('\nBuilding Languages...\n');
    getBaseLanguages(function (files) {
        Promise
            .all(files.map(function (file) {
                return languageBuilder.build(file).then(setAsset);
            }))
            .then(function () {
                callback();
            });
    });

    function setAsset(langs) {
        langs.forEach(function (lang) {
            compilation.assets[lang.path] = {
                source: function () {
                    return JSON.stringify(lang.file);
                },
                size: function () {
                    return lang.file.length;
                }
            };
        });
    }
});
```